# If $\varphi : \mathcal{L}(V) \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $\varphi(ST) = \varphi(S)\varphi(T)$ for all $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, then $\varphi = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Exercise.**

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\text{dim } V > 1$. Show that if $\varphi : \mathcal{L}(V) \to \mathbb{F}$ is a linear map such that $\varphi(ST) = \varphi(S)\varphi(T)$ for all $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, then $\varphi = 0$.

---

**Source.**

Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th edition, by Sheldon Axler.

Chapter 3, section 3B, exercise 32.

---

**Notation used.**

- $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set of all linear transformations from a vector space $V$ to $V$.
- $\mathbb{F}$ represents either the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, or the set of complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$.

---

**What I've tried.**

Axler suggests to use the definition of a two-sided ideal which goes as follows:

> *A subspace $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is called a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ if $TE \in \mathcal{E}$ and $ET \in
> \mathcal{E}$ for all $E \in \mathcal{E}$ and all $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.*

I have shown before that $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$. This implies that for any $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, we have  $ST \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $TS \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.

This implies that $\varphi(TS)$ is well-defined. Since $\varphi(ST) = \varphi(S)\varphi(T)$, we must have then $\varphi(TS) = \varphi(T)\varphi(S)$. It is easy to show that
$$\varphi(S)\varphi(T) = \varphi(T)\varphi(S)$$

This implies that $\varphi(S)\varphi(T) - \varphi(T)\varphi(S) = 0$ which, by the distributive property of linear maps, grants us

$$\varphi(S)[\varphi(T) - \varphi(T)] = 0$$

---

**Question.**

Obviously, this will not lead me to the conclusion $\varphi = 0$. Is this the direction I am meant to go in? Could someone give me a hint?

The only place where I have used the fact that $V$ is finite-dimensional is when showing $\varphi(S)\varphi(T) = \varphi(T)\varphi(S)$ (I omitted this here, but have shown it on paper). Am I supposed to use it elsewhere to help me?

Comment: What you wrote uses commutativity of multiplication in $\Bbb F$, nothing more. Here are two hints: (1) Show $\ker \varphi$ is a two-sided ideal. (2) What are all the two-sided ideals of $\mathcal L(V)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, interesting, I'll give it a shot right now and post a solution once I'm done. For (2), all the two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: Can you find two non-zero $S, T$ such that $ST=0$?  If so, what conclusion can you draw about $\ker \varphi$?

Comment: @RobertShore I'm having a hard time defining two non-zero $S, T$ on the basis of $V$ such that $ST =0$. I know for sure, though, that if $\text{range }T \subseteq \text{null } S$, then $ST =0$. But say that I am able to find such an $S$ and $T$. That will tell me that $\text{ker } \varphi \neq \{0\}$, right?

Comment: Correct.  In fact, given that $\dim V \gt 1$, you should be able to find $S \neq 0$ such that $S^2=0$.

Comment: @RobertShore I have posted my solution based on yours and Ted's comments. I either butchered it or got it right. I didn't justify every detail, but I can justify them on the side if I know the whole is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first show that $\text{ker } \varphi$ is a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

By definition, $$\text{ker } \varphi = \{E \in \mathcal{L}(V) : \varphi(E) = 0\}$$

Consider any $S \in \text{ker } \varphi$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Since $(S\in \text{ker } \varphi) \implies (S \in \mathcal{L}(V))$ we have, by definition of $\varphi$, that $\varphi(ST) = \varphi(S)\varphi(T)$. But $\varphi(S) = 0$ which implies

$$
\varphi(ST) = 0\varphi(T) = 0
$$

This means $ST \in \text{ker } \varphi$. I have shown in my previous response that $\varphi(ST) = \varphi(TS)$. This implies that $TS \in \text{ker } \varphi$ as well. Thus, $\text{ker } \varphi$ is a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

The only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$. Let's now show $\text{ker } \varphi \neq \{0\}$ by showing there exists a non-zero mapping $S \in \text{ker } \varphi$.

Let $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ be a basis of $V$. Define a linear mapping $S: V \to V$ on the basis of $V$ as follows:

- If $n$ is even:
  $$
  Sv_j = 
  \begin{cases}
  v_{j+1},  & j=1, 3, \ldots, n-1 \\
  0, & j=2, 4, \ldots, n
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $n$ is odd:
  $$
  Sv_j = 
  \begin{cases}
  v_{j+1},  & j=1, 3, \ldots, n-2 \\
  0, & j=2, 4, \ldots, n-3, n-1, n
  \end{cases}
  $$

In either case, we'll have that $\text{range }S \subseteq \text{ker }S$. This implies that $S^2 = 0$, which further implies $S^2 \in \text{ker }\varphi$. But by definition of $\varphi$, we have that $\varphi(S^2) = \varphi(S)\varphi(S) = 0$. This implies $\varphi(S) = 0$ and so, $S \in \text{ker }\varphi$. Since $S$ is non-zero, we have that $\text{ker }\varphi \neq \{0\}$. This must mean that $\text{ker }\varphi = \mathcal{L}(V)$, which means that for every linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, we have that $\varphi(T) = 0$, as was to be proven.

Comment: I think it's easier to define $S$ via $S(v_1)=v_2, S(v_k)=0$ for $k=2, 3, \ldots, n$, but your proof is fine.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, your definition is easier on the eye! Thank you for helping me on this, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Chose a base and then regard the transform $L(V)$ as matrix $L(F^n)$.

Now prove that $\ if\ B\ is\ two\ sided\ ideal\ of\ L(F^n)\ and\ B\ is\ not\ \{0\} ,then\ B=L(F^n)$.

Because $B$ is not $\{0\}$, $\exists T \in B , T\neq0$ , so there is i,j satisfy $T(i,j)\neq 0$ .

So $E_{kk}=E_{ki}*T*E_{jk} /T(i,j) \in B$.

So $I=\sum_{k=1}^n E_{kk} \in B$.

So $\forall T \in $L(F^n)$ ,T=T*I \in B$

So $B=L(F^n)$.